# Logo not showing in navbar in ASP.net _layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-core

I am a newbie in asp.net. I m trying to add a logo in my _layout.cshtml file but it's not getting into view. It's showing a broken image. The image is in Assets folder. Don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.
Here's the screenshot of my code and structure.
[image: _layout.cshtml]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For static files in asp.net core, you need to place them in `wwwroot` folder in your project by default.

Follow steps below:

1. Move `Assets` folder to `wwwroot`
2. Change the html code like:

   ```
   <img src="~/Assets/logo.png" />
   ```